# show tables get only the last name of table

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm trying to show the name of table in my database. I write this code :

```
   function affiche_liste()
{   
$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testf','root','');
    $result = $db->query("SHOW TABLES");
       foreach($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) as $data) {
            $tableList = $data[0];
        }
        return $tableList;
}
```

It give to me only the last table ?

Comment: And what you expect from this code?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html  Maybe show tables isn't considerred a valid SQL statement through the Driver... try `SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'` instead? oh and aren't you overwriting your table list data with each record as you process?  `$tableList = $data[0];` seems to just overwrite within the loop.  which would explain why you only display the last one...

Comment: I want to display all my table name exist in database.

Comment: I want to display all my table name exist in database. The same result. I think, i overwriting my table list data with each record in my  process. i do $tableList = $tableList.$data[0];  but doesn't give me a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple query without parameters and the SQL hard coded you can use a generic function passing the connection and SQL to the function.
The following function () returns an array containing all rows in the result set.

```
function queryAll($db,$query){  
    $sth = $db->query($query);
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    return $result;
}
```

For a simple query without parameters and the SQL hard coded you can use a generic function passing the connection and SQL to the function.
The following function () returns an array containing all rows in the result set.

```
function queryAll($db,$query){  
    $sth = $db->query($query);
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    return $result;
}

$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testf','root',''); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = "SHOW TABLES";
$tables = queryAll($db,$query);
print_r($tables);
```

Answer (score -1):

Each time you are looping through the results, your are overwriting the variable `tableList`. Instead, you need to append to an array of results.

```php
function affiche_liste()
{   
    $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testf','root','');
    $result = $db->query("SHOW TABLES");
    $tableList = array();
    foreach($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) as $data) {
        array_push($tableList, $data[0]);
    }
    return $tableList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this 
`

```
function affiche_liste()
{$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testf','root','');
    $result = $db->query("SHOW TABLES");
       foreach($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) as $data) {
            $tableList[] = $data[0];
        }
        return $tableList;
}
```

`

i hope it'll work...
here your array is overwitting every time...that's the reason you were getting the last table name....so you need to append to the existing array...

Comment: I work with service web in the register of method is like this $server->register('affiche_liste',array(),array('return'=>'xsd:string'));  your code give to me a blank page.  I think i have a error in method registration.